# docx4j XHTMLImporter mapping of CSS class names to word format/style

Tags: css, xhtml, docx4j

I would like to use docx4j and the XHTMLImporter to generate a Word file from a given piece of HTML. It works fine except for the fact that I cannot tell the XHTMLImporter to map a CSS class name to a Word format definition. For example, I would like to have XHTMLImporter to do is to map the HTML snippet

```
<p class="AttributeHeadline">some text</p>
```

to "some text" in the generated Word file which is of format/style "AttributeHeadline". The Word document which I load before generating the Word file actually defines that style.

How do I achieve my goal of mapping a CSS class name to a Word format/style name?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either FormattingOption.CLASS_TO_STYLE_ONLY or FormattingOption.CLASS_PLUS_OTHER via setParagraphFormatting or setRunFormatting.

```
package org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml;

/**
 * CLASS_TO_STYLE_ONLY: a Word style matching a class attribute will
 * be used, and nothing else
 * 
 * CLASS_PLUS_OTHER: a Word style matching a class attribute will
 * be used; other css will be translated to direct formatting
 * 
 * IGNORE_CLASS: css will be translated to direct formatting
 *
 */
public enum package org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml;
```

The default is CLASS_PLUS_OTHER, so it should be working as-is.

If it isn't working, then things to check:

- what version of the XHTML importer stuff are you using?  Try http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3_0-beta2.zip
- what exactly is the style ID?  maybe there is a difference is capitalisation/whitespace?

Comment: Upgrading to the newer version actually helped. Now the CSS style is mapped to the Word format style. But Word does not show it: clicking on the text "some text" in the Word document reveals that this text/paragraph is styled with "AttributeHeadline". But looking at the text does not show that the format is actually selected. If I click on the format in the menu or format bar, the text changes its style according to the defined style "AttributeHeadline". I am using Word2010 on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Update to my last comment: The content of the generated xml reveals the problem. The Word format style "AttributeHeadline" sets the font style to bold, but in the generated xml the font style bold is reset: <w:b w:val="false"/>. Likewise the text indentation is set to center in the Word style "AttributeHeadline", but the xml sets it to left: <w:jc w:val="left"/>.

Comment: Use setParagraphFormatting or setRunFormatting as appropriate to set to CLASS_TO_STYLE_ONLY

Comment: I used xHTMLImporter.setParagraphFormatting(FormattingOption.CLASS_TO_STYLE_ONLY); and  xHTMLImporter.setRunFormatting(FormattingOption.CLASS_TO_STYLE_ONLY); , but still the text in the Word document is not styled correctly. The xml reveals the problem: <w:b w:val="false"/><w:color w:val="000000"/>. Additionally, the font size differs from the Word style. This equally holds for the user defined styles as well as the "Standard" Word style.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then.  You can report it, with sufficient steps to repro please, at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues